# cuda-10.1 refuses to go

Tags: nvidia, cuda, tensorflow

After intalling cuda-10.1, I realized that it doesn't work with tensorflow 1.13.1, so I had to downgrade to cuda-10.0.

I tried for a very long time, and at the end seem to have purged 10.1 (`sudo apt purge cuda*`), and then installed 10.0 successfully. However, even after reboot, nvidia-smi still comes up with version 10.1.

I removed `cuda.list` before the purge, as well as the `cuda-10.1` directory under `/usr/local`.

`nvcc --version` now shows 10.0.

How is Ubuntu 16.04 hanging on cuda-10.1?

Comment: What is the output of `nvcc -V`?  As far as I know the `nvidia-smi` reports that even if you don't have CUDA installed at all.

Comment: nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2018 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sat_Aug_25_21:08:01_CDT_2018
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.0, V10.0.130.
not sure I agree if you are saying to ignore what nvidia-smi shows. One evidence is that tensorflow 1.13.1 still can not detect the GPU.

Comment: I am running CUDA 10.1 and my `nvidia-smi` reads CUDA 10.2.  If I uninstall and not have CUDA installed it still reads CUDA 10.2.  This will probably help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53422407/different-cuda-versions-shown-by-nvcc-and-nvidia-smi

Comment: ok, I see there is the possibility of nvidia-smi reporting a different cuda version. This does not move my installation forward however. I know the runtime version is in compliance with the tensorflow version, but tensorflow can't see the gpu still.